# Using VPN for some software but not for others?

Tags: windows-7, browser, vpn, internet-connection, utorrent

I sometime need to use a VPN to access some websites (blocked where I live). However, when I do so I need to close uTorrent otherwise the VPN gets extremely slow and eventually cuts the connection.

So I would like to know: is it be possible to use the VPN just for my browser (i.e. the traffic from/to my browser go through the VPN) and a non-VPN connection for uTorrent (i.e. the traffic from/to uTorrent doesn't go through the VPN)?

I'm on Windows 7.

I'd appreciate any suggestion on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to access some web site, you don't need a full-blown VPN for that. Using a proxy service will suffice. Any modern browser can be configured to use SOCKS proxy... However, there are some limitations:

1. Proxy is not as secure as a real VPN. DNS requests will still go to your ISP, for example.
2. You didn't specify what kind of VPN software or service you use, SOCKS proxy support may not be available there. However, there are free SOCKS proxy server products for both Linux and Windows. If you control the remote point of your VPN, installing something like Squid there is trivial.

But if you just want to access, say, a U.S.-only web site from outside of USA, proxy service will do. Obviously, all browser traffic will go through that proxy, but all other software on your computer will access the net as usual.

This is a strictly technical advise and I don't give any opinion on the legality and/or morality of doing this.